# How can I modify this function to return a Unique ID generated from specific fields?

Tags: r, replace, split, stringr, unique-key

I am writing a Shiny app that writes data from a mock google form into a google Sheet. I want to create a function that uses String modifications to insert a Unique ID based on the user input. This function will be called locally upon downloading the file and reproducibility is very important..so I think it should be dependent on the input and not randomly generated like in the "ids" package...

Here is the sample code for the function:

```
#Unique_id produces a 9 digit code by calling phone number, timestamp, and two letters - first and last name

unique_id <- function(f, l, y, z){

##where f is the column of FIRST NAME

    f %>% str_replace(" ", "") %>% toupper() %>% str_sub(1, 2)

##where l is LAST NAME

    l %>% str_replace(" ", "") %>% toupper() %>% str_sub(1, 2)

##Where y is TIMESTAMP

    y %>% paste0() %>% str_extract("[:digit:][:digit:]-[:digit:][:digit:]") %>% str_replace_all("-", "")

##Where z is phone number formatted NNN-NNN-NNNN

    z %>% str_extract("-[:digit:][:digit:][:digit:]-") %>% str_replace_all("-", "")

##Where UID is the UserID generated...

     UID <- c(f, l , y, z)

    UID <- str_replace("-", "")

    return(UID)
}
```

I suspect that the last block is wrong... but it could all be wrong, I really am just winging this.

Here is a sample of the info that might be in a dataframe I want to call it on...

```
Phone          Address          FirstName  LastName           Timestamp
1 951-349-8967  2134 Road Road   John       jerrod     2018-09-14 20:09:38
2 342-651-3752  154 House St.   Dora       angela     2018-09-14 20:09:38
```

The ideal outcome of calling this function on row 1 would be a UID of JJ0914349. I would then insert it into a new column, the "UID" field.

Right now, I'm getting

```
 Error: Empty `pattern` not supported
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're not passing `UID` to `str_replace`. You should also use `str_replace_all`, so that line would become `UID <- str_replace_all(UID, "-", "")`

Comment: `str_replace` will only replace the first occurrence of the pattern in question, i.e. `str_replace('111-111-1111', '-', '')` returns `111111-1111`. I'm assuming you want to replace all the dashes, hence `str_replace_all`

Comment: Thank you for catching that; I thought I replaced those instances.  
Now when I call the function `unique_id` I get a vector of varying numeric outputs. It's still not the string I was hoping for. Maybe I need to use a different function in place of concatenation?

Comment: You also need to assign the output of each piece back to the object `f`, `y,`, `l`, `z`,  so for `f`: `f <- f %>% str_replace_all(" ", "") %>% toupper() %>% str_sub(1, 2)`. Do that for all four, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the required data are all in fixed positions:

```
DF %>% mutate(id = paste0(toupper(substr(FirstName, 1, 1)),
                          toupper(substr(LastName, 1, 1)),
                          substr(Timestamp, 6, 7),
                          substr(Timestamp, 9, 10), 
                          substr(Phone, 5, 7)))
```

giving:

```
         Phone        Address FirstName LastName           Timestamp        id
1 951-349-8967 2134 Road Road      John   jerrod 2018-09-14 20:09:38 JJ0914349
2 342-651-3752  154 House St.      Dora   angela 2018-09-14 20:09:38 DA0914651
```

### Note

We used this data:

```
Lines <- "Phone,          Address,          FirstName,  LastName,           Timestamp
1,951-349-8967,  2134 Road Road,   John,       jerrod,     2018-09-14 20:09:38
2,342-651-3752,  154 House St.,   Dora,       angela,     2018-09-14 20:09:38"

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is a much more concise route to my solution. Thank you so much!